# How can I use Eye and Hand in The Arch?

Tags: the-age-of-decadence

I think I am stuck, I have found this location called the Arch, spoke to my old raider pal, I got Glove and managed to power it with 3 tubes got an eye too but nothing is happening at The arch when I try to talk to Oracle I don't get dialogue only it says 'The man ignores your presence'.

[image: Screenshot from The Arch]

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Clemnos in the slums near the temple at Maadoran and get the eye surgery then go back there with 3 tubes and the glove.